# Output to LCD is sometimes shifted to the side

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, lcd

I have an Arduino Uno connected to a LCD. When I try to write to it using the LCD library and the following sketch, it will keep shifting the output around, sometimes drastically.

The sketch:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 10, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup () 
{
  lcd.begin (16, 2);
}

void loop () 
{
  lcd.clear ();
  lcd.home ();
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
      lcd.setCursor (j, i);
      lcd.print ("s");
    }
  }

  delay (1000);
}
```

You would expect it to print

> SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
>
> SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

But it will often print

> SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
>
> SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

As in, it skips the first line. And, occasionally, it will even print like this:

> SSSSSSSSSSS
>
> SSSSSSSSSSS

Is it the LCD's fault, or might there be something wrong with the way it is connected?

EDIT:
It is a common Hitachi HD44780-compatible LCD.

EDIT 2:
[image: Fritzing View] Hopefully it is correctly wired up.

Comment: I don't understand that wiring.  What is that regulator doing over to the right, and what is it supposed to be wired to? Where is the power for the LCD coming from?  Where is the contrast trimmer?

Comment: @Majenko The regulator was meant to represent the power. I used that mistakenly (first time using Fritzing. Or doing schematics for that matter). I am not sure how to show the power coming in the breadboard view... What do you mean by contrast trimmer? AFAIK those are all the wire coming out of the LCD.

Comment: @Majenko Hopefully the new image makes more sense

Comment: Is that actually what you're powering the LCD from? Or are you really using a regulated 5V supply?

Comment: It is a regulated 5V supply. I just don't know how to show that in Fritzing

Comment: Ok, one last question before I conclude that I don't have a clue what's happening with your system:  What wire are you using to wire it all up? Type / length / connections, etc.

Comment: Er, dunno, standard wires? Like these: http://i.stack.imgur.com/y7eu5.jpg

Comment: Ok, I have exhausted all the ideas I have at the moment as to why it may not communicate 100%.  It may be down to the LCD possibly - try introducing small delays into your loop - maybe a ms or so after the setCursor - or try doing the setCursor twice in a row.

Comment: I had already tried that. It is most likely the LCD's fault, I just wanted to check for any oversight on my parts. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Try running some example programs. If they work as expected, your LCD is not at fault. Try to use the example wiring (12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2) and don't forget the contrast POT. Why aren't you supplying power (+5V) from the Arduino itself?

Comment: Why do all those `lcd.setCursor`? You cleared the screen, the library should write each letter next to the previous one.

Comment: @MKII Printing the same character over and over ("S", in your case) may be hiding some quirk of the LCD. Change the output line to `lcd.print ((char) 65 + (32 * i) + j);` . This will print capital letters (from 'A') on the top line and the lowercase equivalents on the bottom - that way you'll know immediately if it's shifting left or cuttting off the right.